# flash path for crossdomain.xml

Tags: flash, actionscript, crossdomain.xml

I am new to flash, I had found that my flash swf files need crossdomain.xml file, I just need to deploy the code from one server to another server. But while trying to login to my application. I found that the crossdomain.xml file path points to old server and hence access is restricted, My doubt is where to configure this or This is due to cahce in flash actionscript , how can i clear the cache of action scripts

Comment: If you are testing via a browser, you have just to clear its cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a number of things

Try altering the cross domain XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
    <cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*.example.com"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="www.example.com"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*.adobe.com" headers="SOAPAction"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

[Adobe's page here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/cross-domain-xml-for-streaming.html)

Also check the security policy...

```
System.security.allowDomain("yourdomain.com");
```

If all that still doesn't work, check if you use external actionScript (.as) files, these can become cached in the Flash IDE... try adding a trace command   `trace("cacheClear");` to your external file and republish the affected .fla / .swf files.

That trace will often be enough to get the IDE to notice the change.